# Split google search address

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to split my address (city and street) from google search bar. I will explain better with the pictures.

Here is picture how google find the address.
[image]

Here is the picture then I select the first selection from the google search bar.

[image]

And the problem is. If I press submit button the address is merged.
[image]

Here is javascript code, which I am using.

userAddress = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first").text();

I am just taking the first selection and assign it to the search field.

Comment: Have you tried `.html` instead of `.text`

Comment: it returns the answer:
<span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched">Via Nazionale</span></span><span><span class="pac-matched">Rome</span>, Metropolitan City of Rome, Italy</span>

Answer (score 0):

Since you receive location name and city name as different spans, but separated by `,` using css (probably, as I do not see it in html), just append `,` to location name:

```js
var userAddress = '<div class="google-response">\
  <span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched">Via Nazionale</span></span><span><span class="pac-matched">Rome</span>, Metropolitan City of Rome, Italy</span>\
</div>';

$(document).ready(function () {
  var $html = $('<div>', {html: userAddress});
  var $name = $html.find('.pac-item-query .pac-matched').eq(0);

  $name.text($name.text() + ', ');
  
  
  alert($html.find('.google-response').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It can be a solution if I would have an HTML.  But at this moment I have a variable 'userAddress' which hold html elements with address. In your example jQuery is searching for the classes in HTML document.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But know I have another problem.. For example if i put Ulonu and press ok, I get an answer: 'Verkiu, gatveVilnius, Lithuania'. Anyway, thank you. It helped me.

Comment: Maybe it's because structure is different? Check HTML of it. Beje, labas :D

Comment: taip. I skirtingus spamus deda :/